# CefSharp crashes with "Destroying nonempty message queue"

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

We are writing a program that uses CefSharp to get data from some javascript heavy webpages.

After operating for a while, usually after we are finished but sometimes before, a message is logged to the console saying `Destroying nonempty message queue` and the program freezes.

I am at a loss as I can't even pause the debugger when the message appears, VS crashes with a debugger timeout when trying.

What causes the message queue to be deleted?

Comment: Sounds like you may be breaking a CEF assertion (which kills the process). Are you doing any work on background threads? Have you tried the new version 39?

Comment: I am using version 39. Doing some simple stuff on a callback thread that CEF gives me when I use a bound javascript object, besides that I use tasks which mean I don't know exactly what thread stuff occurs on but it should be mostly on my main thread.

Comment: I should clarify that "Destroying nonempty message queue" is not the cause of the bug.  It is some internal CEF debugging output and is normal (at least, it occurs for me a lot without any crashes).

Comment: Callbacks aren't always called on the right thread to call CEF.  I would add logging prior to all of your CefSharp related calls so you can find out which one is killing it.  It would also be informative to log the thread ID at the same time.  The easiest way to get help with this tricky problem would be to publish your source code or fork the CefSharp MinimalExample to reproduce the problem (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample).

Comment: I don't know if I'll be able to recreate the issue and I doubt I can upload the code itself to git :\ I'll try logging where the calls occur and maybe try to move the calls from the callback thread to the main thread. Can I increase the amount of logging output by CEF? Maybe it will give me some more info.

Comment: You can crank up the logging see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L63

Comment: `Destroying nonempty message queue` is usually safe to ignore see http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12916

Comment: My program stops working after that message, I am stuck waiting for a call from JS running in the browser, I tried skipping the wait and the next call to the browser throws a PipeException saying the pipe channel was closed by the other end.

Comment: So you've crashed the `WCF` channel. The `Destroying nonempty message queue` is likely unrelated. What information can you provide about the call that crashed? How large was the returned message?

Comment: For clarity is the `BrowserSubProcess,exe` still running?

Comment: When the program starts, there are two BrowserSubProcess processes, after the crash only one. The messages aren't very large (I think 4K data at most), but they are pretty fast and frequent. We communicate with the browser by calling ExecuteScriptAsync and returning the results with a bounded object.

Comment: Can you verify that it's the `gpu` process that's still running? So the `WCF channel` has crashed because the `render process` died. Did upping the logging provide anything?

Comment: The crashing process is the renderer process (that's started with `--type=renderer`). The logging doesn't seem to give anything very useful, mostly log calls that say that a resource was loaded. Though we do get a lot of `[0429/105219:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(207)] Running without renderer sandbox` errors. But I understand that this is just misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we did not solve the problem, instead we have figured out a way to tell when the process has crashed (basically we wait for three minutes and if we don't have a reply from the browser we assume it crashed), when the process is stopped we return a partial result to the user and it is the user's responsibility to ask for the rest of the data.

Regarding the crash itself, it isn't clear why exactly but it seems like we are doing something to crash the render process, and because we don't ask for anything over the WCF channel we have no idea that something has crashed.